can someone help me understand how to solve the following tail recursion optimization problem?
Apply tail recursion optimization to the following function and write the target code generated by the optimizing compiler:
int foo(int n, int m) {
    if(n<1)
        return m+1;
    else
        return foo(n/2, m+1);
}

I entered the problem into github copilot to explain to me and received the following answer, but I don't know how to tell if its correct or not and I don't think I should blindly trust it due to it being AI:
The given function is a recursive function but it's not tail recursive because the last operation is not just the recursive call, it also includes an addition operation. To make it tail recursive, we can add an extra parameter to the function to accumulate the result. Here's how you can do it:
int foo_helper(int n, int m, int acc) {
    if(n<1)
        return m+1+acc;
    else
        return foo_helper(n/2, m+1, acc);
}

int foo(int n, int m) {
    return foo_helper(n, m, 0);
}

In this code, foo_helper is a tail recursive function because the last operation in the else clause is the recursive call. The foo function is a wrapper function that calls foo_helper with an initial accumulator value of 0. The optimizing compiler can easily optimize this tail recursive function by transforming it into a loop, which can significantly improve performance for large inputs.

your first function is already recurring in tail position. there's nothing to change. the last operation is the recursive call. a <- n/2, then b <- m+1, then foo(a, b) (tail).

@Mulan could you please explain? are you saying that the problem itself doesn't need to be changed? if you are, I'm not sure what I should answer as my professor gave this in a list of previous midterm questions to practice for an upcoming final exam, there should be some answer no?

you will tell your professor that this particular foo is already written with a tail call. the answer ChatGPT gave you is complete rubbish. the acc is pointless, only adding 0 to the final result.

teachers often use this technique to check for a student's understanding of a particular concept. like "simplify the following fractions: 6/8, 9/24, 1/3, 2/8", 1/3 is already in simplest form, and if the student answers otherwise it indicates a misunderstanding.

"write the target code generated by the optimizing compiler:": the target code generated by a compiler is language specific. For example, in Java it is byte code. What language is the "target code" here?

@trincot it doesnt specify unfortunately, i believe it's just meant as a pseudocode problem

@Mulan, that would be fine if the question asked to turn the function into one that uses a tail call, but that is not the question. It acknowledges that this function has a
tail call, but the question is to apply the optimisation that compilers (that support this kind of optimisation) would apply.

@trincot then what would i do in that case?

@trincot interesting, I see your understanding of the question now. yes, in that case I think your answer is satisfactory.

The challenge asks to apply tail recursion optimization. This is a task that a compiler performs, not the programmer. It then asks you to write the target code generated by the optimizing compiler, but this is ambiguous, because compilers are language specific and generate language specific target code.
Tail call optimization consists of replacing the recursive call by a kind of "goto" statement, without using the call stack. If this challenge really asks us to produce some pseudocode of what the compiler would generate after having applied tail recursion optimization, then translate the recursive solution to an iterative one. In my opinion it's the best you can do with this ambiguous question:
int foo(int n, int m) {
    while (n >= 1) { // Not base case?
        // adapt the parameters for the "tail call"
        n = n / 2;
        m = m + 1;
    } // and go to top to execute it (without using call stack)
    return m + 1; // base case
}


i see, so what you're saying is that the answer would differ language to language if this question were specific, but since it's ambiguous that all we can do is simplify it to the best of our ability

If it would have mentioned the language and compiler, it would be a highly technical question, as you would need to actually analyse what the compiler produced, and I'm not sure how helpful that is. But without those details, you can only answer in generic terms, and only in pseudo code.

Let me know when you have feedback about your teacher (when maybe they score your submission), on whether this was the kind of answer that was expected.

A less sophisticated compiler wouldn't dissemble the if and rewrite the condition like that. Maybe showing while (true) { if (n < 1) break; n = n / 2; m = m + 1; } return m + 1 is a more generic transformation?

Yes, that would approach it a bit more, but it still is pseudocode. In reality it would not even have a while. It will generate lower-level code (like machine code, or byte code), and the call will be replaced with variable assignments and a goto/branch statement. You could also write while (!(n < 1)) ...etc.

To cover for unwanted side-effects of assignments (not here, but in general), you could also generalise with a tuple assignment syntax: [n, m] = [n / 2, m + 1].
